# Why should I run ConfigureServices after ConfigureWebHostDefaults instead of using the ConfigureServices of the startup

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, .net-5

I was reading the docs of msdn. I was wondering why and what's the difference between registering for example an IHostedService in the `ConfigureSerivices` or in the startup `ConfigureServices` method.

I was searching for the difference but I just can't seem to find it. Does anyone know this?

> Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<VideosWatcher>();
        });
```

> Startup.cs

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<VideosWatcher>();
}
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You'd be calling it on the Host and not the web application. Startup can have multiple implementations based on environment. So by calling it in ConfigureServices it's A. Common to everything despite environment  and B. Can help demonstrate/document its unrelated to the web part of the app (for example a background service as in your example)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 so it's only to make it lose of the other environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example the hosted service is run before the web host. If it needs something that is not yet available in the container, you'll have errors. *Nonetheless, this is the common approach for most cases.*

In the first example the hosted service is run after the web host starts (after kestrel starts), so everything will be available.

The docs explain it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#startasync-1).